# SharePoint 2010 MasterPage on SP's Application Pages

Tags: master-page, sharepoint-designer

Running on SharePoint 2010 Foundation. I have created a custom master page which works well for the most part. In SharePoint Designer, I've set the master page as default & custom master pages. When I go to Site Settings, however, the site reverts back to the original master page. When I go to list settings it just displays an error. I don't know if the error is related, but I want to fix the master page issue first. How can I get my master page to be the same across my entire site?

I've created other customer master pages for other site collections on this same server, and they are working fine. Just this one acting up.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, I removed the  since I didn't need it. It appears these app pages need it. Threw it back in and all pages are now using my master page AND the error is gone.